# catplot issue Axes object

Tags: pandas, seaborn, catplot

Supposing I have a Pandas DataFrame variable called df which has columns col1, col2, col3, col4.

Using sns.catplot() everything works fine:

```
fig = sns.catplot(x='col1', y='col2', kind='bar', data=df, col='col3', hue='col4')
```

However, as soon as I write:

```
fig.axes[0].get_xlabel()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_xlabel'
```

I know I can use sns.barplot() with ax parameter but my goal is to keep using sns.catplot() and get an Axes object from fig.axes[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [help page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html), it writes:

> Figure-level interface for drawing categorical plots onto a FacetGrid

So to get the xlabel like you did:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.catplot(x='day', y='tip', kind='bar', data=df, col='smoker', hue='sex')
```

[image]

In this example, you have a facet plot that is 1 by 2, so the axes for the plots are stored in an (1,2) array:

```
g.axes.shape
(1, 2)
```

And to access for example the one of the left (Smoker ="Yes"), you do:

```
g.axes[0,0].get_xlabel()
'day'
```

To change the label:

```
g.axes[0,0].set_xlabel('day 1')
g.fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, you helped me find the solution by myself.

Comment: you're welcome! glad it's useful!